# LINQ - Join Two Entities into One IQueryable Complex Type - EF4 and ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, iqueryable

I have code like:

```
 var entityX = this._xService.GetAll();
 var entityY = this._yService.GetAll();
```

Both are returned as IEnumerable types. I need to inner join the two into a something like a JoinedList class that has to be IQueryable.

I'm looking for ways to do this please using LINQ.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ to Objects is excellent glue:

```
var entityX = this._xService.GetAll();
var entityY = this._yService.GetAll();
var joinedSequence = from x in entityX
                     join y in entityY on x.Key equals y.Key
                     select new { x, y };
var joinedQueryable = joinedSequence.AsQueryable();
```

You shouldn't really *need* that last step; `IQueryable<T>` is unnecessary because LINQ to Objects works just fine with `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: This code will make all the objects in `entityX` and `entityY` load and then filter. Is there a way to load things that fulfill the join condition?